# A FIX msg is broken into 02 parts. How to link these broken set of FIX msgs to make it a complete FIX msg?

Tags: fix-protocol

Lets say, we get the FIX messages from upstream system in the from of XML messages. But these messages are broken into 02 xml messages. All this msgs in xml format is stored in a table.
Now, we have 1000s of these everyday. How to link these pair of messages to each other to have a complete order message/xml ?
Example, the XMLs are loaded in table as :

Row#1
Fixtag8=FIX 4.2, Fixtag9=811,…other FIX tags…, Fixtag123456=C1=
Row#2
|116=Eclipse,…other FIX tags…Fixtag10=122

And similarly we have 1000s of rows of xml data in table. But we are not able to find how to link these pair of broken fix messages.
Is there a way to fix it ?

Let me know if I need to furnish more details

Tx

Comment: This sounds like primary and foreign keys between tables or simply that your persistence is ineffective. I don't think it's so much a FIX protocol question. To fix it you need a key between the rows...

Comment: If those are in sequence, why can't you check start (Fixtag8) and end tag (Fixtag10)?